# Is there a way to activate maintenance mode if the server is down?

Tags: php, laravel, maintenance-mode

Is there a way to automatically show maintenance mode in Laravel when the server is down? I know there is command `php artisan down` or upload down file to `store/framework`, but when server is down, I can't upload or call the command.

How to show maintenance mode when server is down?

Comment: When the server is down, there is no laravel to show the maintenance message.

Comment: @tkausl Exactly, i thought like you said. But customer said that is possible :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a load balancer
2. Use cloudflare, but it won't show a maintenance screen, just that the website is offline